# Iterar en Python sobre lista anidada

Tags: python

Tengo una lista anidada y quisiera sacar los números contiguos dentro de la lista anidada .con este código(gracias al aporte de Christian):

```
contiguos = []

listas = [[1,2,7,9],[3,4,9,9,4]]

for lista in listas:                  
    for element in range(len(lista)-1):
        if lista[element] == lista[element+1]-1:
            contiguos.append((lista[element],lista[element+1]))
print(contiguos)
```

Obtengo los contiguos dentro de la sublista ->  `[(1,2),(3,4)]`

Pero lo q estoy intentando es sacar los contiguos que hay no en cada su lista, sino tomando como referencia ambas sublistas y sacar los contiguos que hay en ellas. Es decir el resultado q busco tomando el ejemplo anterior sería `[(2,3)]` que son los únicos números contiguos de ambas sublistas

Comment: creo que el resultado que esperas esta mal, pues `1` es contiguo de `2` y este a su vez es contiguo de `3` que también es contiguo de `4`, por ende el serultado seria `[(1,2,3,4)]`

Comment: Creo que hacen falta una explicación más completa y más ejemplos. ¿Siempre hay solo dos sub-listas? ¿Qué tendría que pasar si tengo `[1,3,5][2,4,6]`? ¿Si tengo [1,3,5][6,4,2]?

Comment: um... quieres que de cada element de listas[0] comprobar que existe un número contiguo en listas[1]?

Comment: por ejemplo dada la lista dada esperas este resultado?
[(2,3)] ya que es el unico elemento de listas[0] que tiene contiguo en listas[1]?

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como información inicial que buscas generar una lista de tuplas donde cada tupla es el resultado de una comparación de numeros contiguos de dos listas (teniendo una de ellas como base):

```
contiguos = []
listas = [[1,2,7,9,10],[3,4,9,9,4,11]]


for element in listas[0]:
    if (element+1) in listas[1]:
        contiguos+=[(element,element+1)]
        
print(contiguos)
#[(2, 3), (10, 11)]
```

Comment: lo siento decepcionarte pero es el mismo código del ejemplo pero simplificado, pues el resultado es el mismo

Comment: El codigo de la publicación da los contiguos de la misma lista, este busca los contiguos que se encuentren entre dos listas
,resultado con el codigo de publicación: `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]` 
,resultado del codigo propuesto: `[(2, 3)]`

Comment: Haa.. lo siento :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con comprensión de listas:

```
listas = [[1, 2, 7, 9], [3, 4, 9, 9, 4]]

print([(n, n+1) for n in listas[0] if n + 1 in listas[1]])
```

Devuelve `[(2, 3)]`

```
listas = [[1, 2, 7, 9], [3, 4, 9, 8, 4]]

print([(n, n+1) for n in listas[0] if n + 1 in listas[1]])
```

Devuelve `[(2, 3), (7, 8)]`

Siempre y cuando solamente vayas a tener dos listas dentro de `listas`.